# Write factorial with (generalized) arrows in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, arrows

I would like to write a factorial in `(->)` arrow in Haskell. I don't get how do I translate recursion into `loop`. I've managed to use `loop` to make a fixpoint for my factorial, but now there's a problem with lambda-abstraction, which I cannot translate.

```
loop f b = let (d, c) = f (d, b) in c
g = \(f, x) -> (\x -> if x == 0 then 1 else x * f (x - 1), f x)
main = print $ loop g 5
```

There's an [article](http://onthebalcony.wordpress.com/2007/02/19/my-evolution-as-a-haskell-programmer/) on writing factorial in another arrow that transforms streams: `[a] -> [b]`, but that's not the case I'm interested in. What I'm looking for is more [like that](http://www.megacz.com/berkeley/garrows/flattening.examples/index.html).

How do I write factorial in `(->)` arrow?

Comment: `loop` is just a version of `fix` for `Arrow`. `g` is already an arrow you want to `loop` over. So I guess you've already managed to write factorial in `(->)` arrow.

Comment: `g` is already an arrow: it has type `(Int -> Int, Int) -> (Int -> Int, Int)`.

Comment: @fizruk I'm trying to decompose that whole function into arrow primitives. Imagine that there's no `arr` constructor. Here's an example: http://ideone.com/YHzZFJ

Comment: http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html

Comment: @Owen @fizruk Uh, by the way, I did it. Took some time and two questions on `cstheory` to figure out that there is a GArrowLoop on Either. When I've got that it's just another example of traced monoidal category, I wrote it. http://ideone.com/pgb9YK

Comment: What exactly do you mind about type signatures, incidentally? They would make your code about an order of magnitude easier to understand...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Those should be orgamized into type classes. The real types (http://www.megacz.com/berkeley/garrows/) are a little bit more complicated than the ones used in those functions, so I didn't mind writing them.

Comment: Wow, that shouldn't be kappa-calculus http://conal.net/blog/posts/overloading-lambda

Answer (score 1):

Here is the equivalent recursive definition of the factorial function in Haskell arrow notation.

```
fact :: Integer -> Integer
fact = proc b -> do
    rec
        c <- f -<< b
        f <- g -< f
    returnA -< c

g :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Integer -> Integer
g f x = if x == 0 then 1 else x * f (x-1)
```

The second line of the recursive blocks makes evident the fact that the factorial function is the fixed point of `g`.  In the first line, a higher-order arrow application `-<<` is needed since `f` is also an arrow within the block.  The line could also have been written

```
c <- app -< (f,b)
```

It's not immediately clear if a definition is possible in recursive arrow notation by defining only data, i.e., without higher-order arrow application.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to first convert recursion into using `fix`, and then implement `fix` using `loop`:

```
import Control.Arrow

fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix = loop (\(f, x) -> let x' = f x in (x', x'))
```

Or point-free using the arrow notation:

```
fix = loop (uncurry ($) >>> (id &&& id))
```